# SfTabView header clips zooming image

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, uiscrollview, syncfusion, zooming

We have SfTabView with each tab hosting UITableView as child contents. We allow zooming-in of UIImageView hosted inside of UIScrollView inside table cell. When user zooms in, image is properly zoomed, but the header of SfTabView clips the image, though we set 'Layer.ZPosition = 1000' of cell and image being zoomed, and though we set SfTabView.ClipsToBounds and its childs to 'false'.

What could be the cause?

[image]

Code:

```
void HandleZPositionInRecursions(UIView v)
        {
            if (v != null)
            {
                v.ClipsToBounds = false;
                v.Layer.ZPosition = 1;

                foreach (var child in v.Subviews)
                {
                    if (child != null)
                    {
                        child.ClipsToBounds = false;
                        child.Layer.ZPosition = 1;

                        HandleZPositionInRecursions(child);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

We explicitly set zooming image and scroll view to be at the top on zoom action:

```
 imageScrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView += (UIScrollView sv) =>
        {
            UITableView tab = null;
            this.Table.TryGetTarget(out tab);
            tab.ScrollEnabled = false;

            var parentView = sv.Superview;
            while (parentView != null)
            {
                parentView = parentView.Superview;

                if (parentView is SfTabView sfTabView)
                {
                    HandleZPositionInRecursions(parentView);
                }
            }

            this.Layer.ZPosition = 1000;
            imageView.Layer.ZPosition = 1000;
            sv.Layer.ZPosition = 1000;
            this.Superview.Layer.ZPosition = 100;

            tab.ClipsToBounds = false;
            imageScrollView.ContentSize = new`enter code here` CGSize(imageView.Frame.Width, imageView.Frame.Height);
            return imageView;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from Syncfusion.

We have checked the code snippet provided in your update and we have modified your code snippet to resolve the issue you are facing. Could you please check the below code,

**Code Snippet:**

```
void HandleZPositionInRecursions(UIView v)
    {
        if (v != null && !(v is SfTabView))
        {
            v.ClipsToBounds = false;
            v.Layer.ZPosition = 1;

            foreach (var child in v.Subviews)
            {
                if (child != null)
                {
                    child.ClipsToBounds = false;
                    child.Layer.ZPosition = 1;

                    HandleZPositionInRecursions(child);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Sample** https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/TabViewNativeSample-673496616

Please check with the above and let us know if you have any concerns.

Regards,

Rabhia Beham.K

Comment: Unfortunately, we tried but it still doesn't work correctly.